# What does whole-animal mean?

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain the meaning of *whole-animal*

> The Country Cat (restaurant) is known for whole-animal, farm-to-table scratch cooking, and at PDX Sappington was determined to break down animals, smoke meats, and make scratch pastries — all out of a 700-square-foot kitchen in the terminal.

Comment: Means they arrive under their own steam, after which they're prepared and served whole. How quaintly medieval.

Comment: @AlinaSaidova http://thecountrycat.net/about-us/

Comment: Doubtless the menu will be printed on their own hand-made vellum.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, and in blood, no doubt.

Comment: @terdon: I suppose the cited text is supposed to be a glowing endorsement of the one-stop-shop "pigsty to table" approach, but I gotta say ***breaking down animals*** sounds more like industrialised gimmickry / money-making than *haute cuisine*. Me, I draw the line at choosing my own lobster from the tank in the restaurant foyer. (Every time I see one, I weep over what Homer Simpson did to our beloved [Pinchy](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Pinchy)! :)

Comment: @AlinaSaidova I would suspect it's a paleo/WAPF friendly restaurant. https://www.paleohacks.com/paleo/are-there-more-restaurants-like-dick-s-kitchen-in-portland-11617 Whole, grass-fed/organically farmed animals are used for their recipes. Hardly anything goes to waste: the meat is served with the fat, the pastries are baked with lard or tallow, the skin and bones are boiled to make gelatin, sausage is made from the blood and the organs, etc.

Comment: Almost all restaurants buy pieces of meat and not whole animals. The Country cat is perhaps an exception.

Comment: In one of his books, Farley Mowat gave a recipe for souris à la crème.  (Mice in crème).  The wolves he was observing got a substantial portion of their diet from mice, and was incredulous that a large mammal could exist on mice.  So he did the experiment on himself. Considering the name of the restaurant, one has to wonder.....